# matrix addition using c

Tags: c, matrix, addition

I was giving an assignment to work on addition of matrices using C ,I use a Dev C++ IDE version 5.71 ,I tried using this code but its not compiling

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    int a, b ,c ,d, mat1[20][20],mat2[20][20], matAdd[20];

    //a = row number ,b = column no 
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns:\n");

    scanf("%d%d", &a,&b);

    printf("Enter elements of matrix one:\n");

    for (c =0; c < a; c++){
        for (d=0; d < b; d++){
            scanf("%d", &mat1[c][d]);
         }
    }
    printf("Enter elements of matrix two:\n");

    for (c =0; c < a; c++){
        for (d = 0; d < b; d++){
            scanf("%d", &mat2[c][d]);
        }
    }

    printf("Addition of the two matrices is below:\n");

    for (c =0; c < a; c++){
        for (d=0; d < b; d++){

        matAdd[c][d] = mat1[c][d] + mat2[c][d]; 
        printf("%d\t",matAdd[c][d]); 
    }
    printf("%n");
    getch();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Here are the errors I receive.

```
Line:35 Col:12 [Error] subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector
Line:36 Col:26 [Error] subscripted value is neither an array nor pointer nor vector
Line:45 Col:1 [Error] expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Comment: Please edit your code and give us your compiler errors as text.

Comment: the error is in the  picture attached

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Also, please read this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/222049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo: your definition `matAdd[20]` should be `matAdd[20][20]`.

Comment: Matrix multiplication needs 3 nested loops: 2 loops to iterate over each element of the result matrix, and for each such element another iteration to calculate the result of multiplying the appropriate row and column. See http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/c-program-to-multiply-two-3-x-3.html for an example.

Comment: But you should really try a little harder yourself first, both to figure out the answer *and* before posting on Stack Overflow.